# Django link to existing item or create if unique in multi-model form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a form which uses multiple models, which have relationships. If the data for one of the forms matches an existing entry, I want to have the foreign key map to the existing entry rather than create a duplicate entry.  However, is_valid() fails for the already existing entry and I'm not sure if it is safe to use the form data before it has been cleaned to do a database lookup for existence first.  Perhaps I need to change the clean function to ignore the uniqueness requirement and then handle it in the view?

Here's an example, a user enters their name, city and state in a web form.  If that city is already known to the database, then the foreign key for the person should just point to the existing entry.  If it is a new city, it should be added to the database.  So it is always a CREATE for Person, but it may or may not be a CREATE for Hometown.

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    hometown = models.ForeignKey('Hometown')

class Hometown(models.Model):
    cityName = models.CharField()
    stateName = models.CharField()
    mascot = models.CharField()

    #If same city and state, it's the same place
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("cityName", "stateName")
```

forms.py

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('hometown')

class HometownForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hometown
```

views.py

```
def newPerson(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        person = PersonForm(request.POST)
        hometown = HometownForm(request.POST)
        if (person.is_valid() and hometown.is_valid():
            p = person.save(commit=False)
            h = Hometown.objects.get_or_create(**hometown.cleaned_data)
            p.hometown = h
            p.save()
```

This code doesn't work, because hometown.is_valid() will be False if that city/state pair is already in the database.  Should I override the clean() function to allow ignore the uniqueness requirement (enforcing it in the view by using get_or_create) or is that an indication that my design is fundamentally the wrong way of addressing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question on stackoverflow contained the information I needed.  [Free-form input for ForeignKey Field on a Django ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137196/free-form-input-for-foreignkey-field-on-a-django-modelform?rq=1)

As applied to my original question, I removed the HometownForm and instead added the relevant fields to PersonForm, then made the save() function of PersonForm handle the get_or_create() behavior for the Hometown.